# how to change the created date of a folder in sharepoint

Tags: powershell, folder

I have a document library, I have used a powershell command to change the created date of the files uploaded in that library. However, I also want to change the created date of a Folder which is uploaded in that library. Please suggest a powershell command.

Answer (score 2):

Try this PS snippet:

```
$foldersColl = $oList.GetItems($folderquery) 
foreach($folder in $foldersColl) 
{ 
    $folder["Created"] = $dateToSet 
    $folder.Update()  
}
```

Updated answer (after reading comments)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = get-SPWeb "http://portal/";
$list =$web.lists["Documents"];
$folderName = "BNFSDocs";
$item = $list.folders | ? {$_.Name -eq $folderName} 
$dateToStore = Get-Date "10/02/1984" 
$item["Created"] = $dateToStore 
$item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

Comment: Thanks ALexander. But pls help me. This is my PS code.
$url = "http://synpunspd0366:44175/sites/SAMS/KR"
$listName = "Domain"
$folderName = "BNFSDocs"
 
#Get the appropriate list from the web
$web = get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.lists[$listName]
 
#Get the file using the filename
$item = $list.Items | ? {$_.Name -eq $folderName}
 $dateToStore = Get-Date "10/02/1984"
$item["Created"] = $dateToStore
 $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
But it is giving error,where to put your snippet?pls help

Comment: Alexander I dont want to use foreach, I just have one folder in my library as BNFSDOcs want to change its created date

Comment: I edit my answer. You must use $list.folders not $list.items

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass parameters to powershell command? I need to pass folder name and created date.

Comment: Read this article https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-p-is-for-parameters

Comment: I did that. But I am facing a small problem. If I have to change a file's created date which is inside a folder then? It is not working. Please help

Comment: So, you need to change folder date and all date of all files inside?